# How to print a random String in Swift in TextView?

Tags: ios, swift

I've stored several sentences in an array:

```
let sentences = ["This is example 2","This is the second example", "The last example"]
```

One of these string should be shown in my TextView by random.
Can you help me how I can do this with Swift?

Answer (score 0):

I am answering this question keeping in mind a general approach. I am not keeping in mind the Programming language you are working on. Keeping in mind the time factor. Get the timestamp from system in milliseconds and take mod of 3 this way you will always get a random number in [0,1,2]

```
index = timestamp_in_milliseconds % 3
sentences[index]
```